How to compare the mean of different variables?
I am working on factors causing culture shock. I designed a questionnaire regarding 7 different factors which could be the cause of culture shock. I calculated the mean of each factor by averaging the students' responses. I need to rank the factors from highest to lowest according to intensity of effect. How can I compare these factors's effect? I already compared the factors by ranking the means of each factor as shown in the attached figure. Is there any other way or statistical test(e.g paired samples t-test) which I can use to compare these factors. Thank you


"Effect" on what?

It's generally easier for people to respond if you only include an image where you have to - I would put the details as text, not an image.

You should explain clearly what you are measuring. I am guessing (??) that the variable may be a score on a Likert scale; in which case, even computing a mean is questionable (Likert scores are ordinal variables, not interval/ration variables: any arhitmetic on Likert scores is invalid...). But then again it may be something else. Can you clarify what it is that you are taking the means of?

@jginestet I'm measuring whether a factor is the cause of culture shock or not. For each factor I have asked multiple questions. The response of each question is between 1 to 5. I calculated the score of each student. The mean shown in the table is the average score of 100 students. My question is: Is there any way to compare the means through a statistical test?

So, as I assumed, your initial data are ratings on a 5 point Likert scale (1=Fully disagree, ... to Fully agree=5). If not, please explain how the 1-5 score is established. If my (now educated guess) is correct, this is the neginning of the end for your approach. These 1-5 scores are on an ordinal scale (You know that 1 is less than 2, but you do not know my how much (1 unit of what?); nor is 2 agreeing twice as much as 1, etc...) So you can not do any math with these values, let alone averaging them for each student, let alone averaging the averages accross all students....

... So do not even try to compute means, or even worse compare them. Instead look at your data as categorical; you have 5 categories (1 for each level in your Likert scale), and you have counts for each category, and each question. Say you had 10 factors, 5 categories, and 100 students: you have a 10 columns by 5 rows table of counts. You can them compare the counts for each factor and test if they are the same, or not. Search for nxM contingency tables, multinomial tests, etc. You most likely will need some specialized software for this.
